# how to implement this code on atmega32

Tags: c, microcontroller, avr, atmega

one of my DIY prjects has this code for converting GPS coordinates to nmea format, but i am unable to do so also i don't know which headers to add before the code so can any body help me out on this

```
private string DD2NMEA(double lat, double lng)
{
string nmea = "";
double lata = Math.Abs(lat);
double latd = Math.Truncate(lata);
double latm = (lata - latd) * 60;
string lath = lat > 0 ? "N" : "S";
double lnga = Math.Abs(lng);
double lngd = Math.Truncate(lnga);
double lngm = (lnga - lngd) * 60;
string lngh = lng > 0 ? "E" : "W";

nmea += latd.ToString("00") + latm.ToString("00.00000") + "," + lath + ",";
nmea += lngd.ToString("000") + lngm.ToString("00.00000") + "," + lngh;

return nmea;
}
```

Comment: This looks like Java...

Answer (score 0):

That looks like something for the standard [Ardunio math module](http://arduino.cc/en/Math/H), available by doing

```
#include <math.h>
```

You will have to adapt the syntax, e.g. `Math.Abs()` becomes just `fabs()`.

If you're not doing this on Arduino but using the AVR directly, it's exactly the same since Ardunio just inherits the C header and functions here.